# Problem with localization to Persian language

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to localize [thekordy/ticketit][1] to Persian language but some of my content are translated correctly and others have utf-8 problem and are display as  `ØªÛÚ©Øª ÙØ§Û ÙØ¹Ø§Ù`.

I put charset utf-8 in every blade and also put `\Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');` in my service provider but again I have the problem and at last I tried to run `php artisan vendor:publish` this code in my comment prompt and also I publish `Tag:lang` successfully but my blade again have that Unicode problem, I've attached a screenshot of my blade at the end of this message, what should I do to solve this problem and localize my ticketit correctly?

Comment: Is your DB collation set to `utf-8` or `utf8-mb4`?

Comment: translation is loaded from a file which is located in my vender of laravel,and also my DB collation is set to utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the HTML charset attribute is set to utf-8.
You could try

```
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true);
```

to make sure the translation text you added is UTF-8.